Cold water storage tank at 60F: safe from bacteria etc?
I'm planning to replace my current 50-gallon conventional electric water heater with a hybrid heat pump model, for the electricity savings.
The current one is located in the laundry room, but I want to install the new one in the garage, to keep noise away from the living space.
The current tank is in good shape, so I'm thinking of leaving it in the laundry room and repurposing it as a cold water storage tank, to have an extra 50 gallons of cold water for emergencies/outages/general preparedness.
The average incoming water temperature is around 60 degrees F.
I could pipe it inline ahead of kitchen and laundry room cold water supply, so cold water is constantly flushed through daily. Would this keep it safe from bacteria build-up?
I assume the anode rod would continue to offer protection, and therefore still need periodic replacement. Any other maintenance or concerns with cold water storage tanks?

interesting concept, they use UV light in the water filtration systems to kill bacteria on the outlet

So you should check out legionella. Compare your temperatures to the breeding temperature etc.

What's your water source? Municipal water, or well?

Water source is municipal.  I checked out legionella; recommendations are temperature above 140F or below 68F, and no standing/still water. So it seems like my plan would meet those criteria at face value. Just hoping to hear from someone with more direct experience.  I will check out the uv light idea.

How would you use the water in the cold tank?

In a loss of water pressure, faucets would still drain the upper half of the tank, from basic hydrostatic pressure in the pipes.  For the lower half of the tank, there is a drain valve at the bottom of the tank, to fill other containers from.  I would probably put the tank up on a short pedestal to make that easier.

The University of Florida, a state not known for bone-chilling tap water, publishes an informative page about storing water.
Municipal water by law (in the U.S.) is either treated with a disinfectant such as chlorine or it comes from a sterile source such as a deep well. As such, it is safe to store municipal water indefinitely, with six months the recommended maximum for taste reasons per the above link. This assumes that all of your plumbing is sealed and you are not using a cistern or anything that exposes your drinking water to the atmosphere.
Since you would be continuously adding new water to your storage tank through daily use, you should have no issues whatsoever with water safety. If your lifestyle has you away from home for a few months at a time, it may be best to run fresh water through your plumbing to flush out any off-tastes.

That's great info; thank you.
